# Active tickmark on page load in selected dropdown item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, .net

I have written a JavaScript to show a tick mark just to the right side of the selected drop-down item (CSS class name `active`):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.select-country ul li a').click(function () {
        $('.select-country ul li a').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Its works well, but I have a problem here.

**Problem:**

When I refresh the page the drop-down will default to a default selected item. But that selected item is not showing the tick mark.

How do I rewrite the query to show the tick mark for the default selected item in drop-down?

Comment: can you create jsfiddle for it?

Answer (score -1):

You need to `loop` over the `li` so that respective links are responsible for there own events,

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.select-country ul li a.default').addClass("active");
    //loop over all li
    $('.select-country ul li a').each(function () {
        //remove first from any active link
        $(this).click(function(){
            $('.select-country ul li a').removeClass("active");
           //find and add active on "this" link
           $(this).addClass("active");

           return false; 
        });

    });
});
```